# Wrapping text with span, based on start:end points given numerically in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Not to long ago I was asked a question that for some reason I can't wrap my head around, cause I could think of better faster less expensive ways to do it to a point. However the answer wasn't what was wanted, nor did it fit the criteria 100% so I am still haunted by this question passively thinking about it from time to time, would someone please show me how I can do this cleanly?

**Let's say I have an array:**

```
[
   [0,6],
   [10,19],
   [21,40],
   [8,25],
   [75,100]
]
```

**And this string:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id arcu pretium, fringilla ante a, elementum nulla. Maecenas placerat libero vel interdum ultrices. Nulla viverra nulla mauris, nec lacinia ligula elementum nec. Mauris suscipit blandit nulla, eu scelerisque mauris egestas ornare. Quisque lorem velit, fermentum in quam eget, consequat tincidunt.

**The end result should be..**

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </span>adipiscing elit. Duis id arcu pretium, fringilla <span>ante a, elementum nulla</span>. Maecenas placerat libero vel interdum ultrices. Nulla viverra nulla mauris, nec lacinia ligula elementum nec. Mauris suscipit blandit nulla, eu scelerisque mauris egestas ornare. Quisque lorem velit, fermentum in quam eget, consequat tincidunt.
```

**And not be...**

```
<span>Lorem </span>ipsu<span>m dol<span>or si</span>t amet, consectetur </span>adipiscing elit. Duis id arcu pretium, fringilla ante a, elementum nulla. Maecenas placerat libero vel interdum ultrices. Nulla viverra nulla mauris, nec lacinia ligula elementum nec. Mauris suscipit blandit nulla, eu scelerisque mauris egestas ornare. Quisque lorem velit, fermentum in quam eget, consequat tincidunt.
```

Whats the best way to handle it so any overlapping spans while wrapping multiple areas with spans?

Answer (score 0):

So your array of arrays, with start and end refer to words, words are separated by spaces. If this is the only guarantee then you can use `string.split(' ')` to get an array of words, and use their index's to compare to the array of arrays.

So..

```
 var stringOfStuff = 'Hello My Name Is Rhys';
 var spanStartAndEnds = [ [0, 1] ];
 var words = stringOfStuff.trim().split(' ');
 //we have to trim or this wont work with split

 for(var i = 0; i < spanStartAndEnds.length; i++) {
   for(var j = 0; j < spanStartAndEnds[i].length; j++) {
     for(var x = 0; x < words.length; x++) {
       if(x == j) {
         //do something to add span. (maybe recurse with array input with new spans.)
       }
     }
   }
 }
```